# field.getName() return wrong name if field is protected

Tags: android

In my android application, there is class like

```
class Tool {
   protected final long ID = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
   private String name;
   private int size;
}
```

I use the following code to get name of all declared fields of this class

```
for (Field f: Tool.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
   System.out.println(f.getName());
}
```

When I built APK in debug mode, f.getName() method return correct name of fields ("ID", "name", "size")
But when i generate singed APK for release, getName() method of protected ID field will become "a" not "ID" as I expected while other private and public fields still return correct name.

Here is my grade configuration

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 151
        versionName "1.51"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        renderscriptTargetApi 24
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

        // Enabling multidex support.
        // Fix: the number of method references cannot exceed 64K
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    // Fix error of out of memory when build APK
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help. Thanks.

### FIXED

I found that i miss adding protected to this configuration in proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class * {
    public private protected *;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably due to [minification and proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html).

Try to disable those two in your `release` in your `gradle` and check again.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Following your suggestion, I found the problem come from proguard configuration. I miss adding protected to -keep class * {
    public private *;
}

Comment: @hauca Please, do accept the answer if it answers your question.